# What's a neat way to convert a single value to an array with a single element?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm calling a method which takes an array of integers representing IDs of records to be deleted:

```
service.Delete(IDArray)
```

However I only want to delete a single record so I only have a single value. Obviously I could do something like this:

```
Dim IDArray(0) as Integer
IDArray(0) = ID
service.Delete(IDArray)
```

However it looks quite kludgy. Is there a **neat** way to do this in a single line with some sort of clever array construction syntax?

Comment: `service.Delete({ID})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty neat:

```
service.Delete(New integer(0){ID})
```

and, as Dominc suggests, this is even neater (although I like being explicit):

```
service.Delete({ID})
```

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_CreatingAnArray).

Comment: No need to specify the type. `service.Delete({ID})` is enough.

Comment: Also, when you do specify the type, you don't need to specify the length (unless you really want to), for instance: `service.Delete(New Integer(){ID})`.